Is it true that if he plays long enough there will be a series of consecutive days during which he will play exactly 23 games?
Grandmaster Lev Alburt plays at least one game of chess a day to keep in shape and not more than 10 games a week to avoid tiring himself out.  Is it true that if he plays long enough there will be a series of consecutive days during which he will play exactly 23 games?
Clarification:
After posting this question, I realized the word “week” is ambiguous.  Let’s assume it means any period of seven consecutive days.
Attribution:
Mostly Southampton Mathematical Olympiad, 1986;
Partly me.

Very similar https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/127866/71595.

Does the weekly limit apply to standard weeks (e.g., Mon-Sun), or is it a rolling total for any period of seven consecutive days?

@noedne Thanks for your question!  I have updated my question to define “week” as any 7 consecutive days.

You might be interested: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4992565/how-is-this-question-on-the-puzzling-se-not-trivial

This is

 true.

Designate an arbitrary Monday as day 1 and let $a_1,a_2,...$ denote the sequence in which $a_k$ is the total number of games played up until day $k$.
Now,

 among the first 24 numbers $a_k$ in that list, there must be two that leave the same remainder after division by 23. Let $a_i, a_j$ with $i<j$ be two such numbers. Since Lev plays at least one game a day, these two numbers cannot be the same. But also, since the 24 days fall into the span of only four weeks, these numbers must differ by less than 40 (even less actually, but that doesn't matter). Hence, their difference must be exactly 23, which means that he must have played exactly 23 games in the span of the $(i+1)$-st and $j$-th day.


This would be better if you explained "why" on the "there must be two" sentence. It's the pigeonhole principle, but spell it out instead of just asserting it.

This was much easier for me to follow than the other solution, thank you!

Here's an alternative proof that's far less elegant, but is accessible to younger solvers.

 The 10 max per 7 day restriction means that the most possible games per day is 4, so any set of four 1s in a row will result in a string adding up to 23. This is because I can start at the first 1 and add from there until I get more than 23. This number can be 26 at most (22 and then the 4), and thus I get 23 by starting instead at the fourth 1.


 But to have a 4 in the first place, it needs to have six 1s after it, so having a 4 at all necessarily produces a subsequence with sum of 23. Thus, if it is possible to come up with a sequence without a subsequence adding up to 23, the largest number of games per day is actually 3. But by the same logic, that means any sequence of three ones yields a string totalling to 23, and a 7 day period starting with a 3 has three 1s in a row. So actually the supposed sequence must be all 1s and 2s!


 But then any sequence with two ones in a row yields a 23 subsequence. Again, a 7 day sequence starting with a 2 that totals 10 or less must have two 1s in a row, and so it is altogether impossible to construct a sequence under the given restrictions such that has no subsequence has a sum of 23.


This was much easier for me to follow than the other solution, thank you! One minor nitpick that doesn't really change the integrity of the solution at all: (rot 13) gurer VF n jnl gb nygreangr barf naq gjbf va nal tvira jrrx (1212121), ohg guvf jvyy bayl shapgvba sbe bar jrrx, nf gelvat gb ercrng vg jvyy erfhyg va n frdhrapr jvgu gjb pbafrphgvir barf ng gur raq bs gur svefg jrrx naq gur fgneg bs gur frpbaq.

Oops! Fixed it.


 He'll play at least 4 days once a day in a week, and can play at most 4 times on a single day. He can play 23 games within at least 15 days.  Let the number of times he played chess each day be $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, ..., x_{n-3},x_{n-2},x_{n-1},x_n, y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4$.  Take $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + ... + x_{n-3} + x_{n-2} + x_{n-1} + x_n = A$. For $A+1$ to be unreachable, none of $y_1, y_1 + y_2, y_1 + y_2 + y_3$ or $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4$ can be $1$ more than any of $x_1, x_1 + x_2, x_1 + x_2 + x_3$ or $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4$. Also, $y_1>1$.  Regarding these expressions, if there are $k$ terms in one, it can range from $k$ to $k+3$, meaning $y_2, y_3$ and $y_4$ can't be all $1$ at once, and by extension $y_1<4$. If anything, no $y$ can be $4$.  If $y_2=y_3=1$, then $y_1-1, y_1$ and $y_1+1$ are all off-limits for the expressions with $x$ numbers, so if there are $y_1-1$ terms in such a sum, it'll amount to $y_1+2$. If $y_1=2$, $x_1=4$, and the other $x$es are $1$, which would make this impossible.  If there are two $1$s in a row among the $y$s, let the sum of the portion coming before them be $m$. Then anything from $m-1$ to $m+1$ is off limit for $x$es. For the starting $m-1$ terms, $m+2$ is the sum. For $m-2$ terms, $m-2$ is. The $y$ portion can consist of $1$ or $2$ terms, so it can sum up to $5$, meaning $x_{m-1}=4$. If $m=3$, it can't be satisfied. For $m=4$, no. For $m=5$, no.  For $2121, 2131, 3121$, no solution is possible.  For $2122, 2212, 2221$, no solution is possible.  Which means if he plays for long enough, he can play $23$ matches by extension.


He plays no more than 10 games a week.
Therefore he can play only one game each day in a week as this is no more than 10.
So if he plays one game per day for 23 days, he will have a consecutive period over which he will play 23 games

He doesn't have to play the same number of games on each day

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

@TimSeifert sure, but he can. And it answers the question

@Piro It really doesn't. The question asks, if such a streak will necessarily happen, not just if it is possible. (What kind of a puzzle would that be?)

@Piro It's about whether he can no matter how many times he plays each day. 1, 2, 3, 4, doesn't matter. Sure, he can just play a single game each day in a 23-day streak, but what if he doesn't?
